# Unity 2D - using raycast to detect collision for 2D arkanoid/breakout game

Tags: collision-detection, raycasting, unity-game-engine, breakout

can anyone give me any advice on how to use 2d recasting in Unity to detect fast moving collision for a 2d breakout game as the normal collision method isn't working for me due to fast moving ball objects.

Also if there are any good tutorials anyone can point to that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks